# Strange padding issue in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, padding

On [this website](https://www.loganta.be) I'm encountering a problem with IE11, who seems to remove all padding from my content elements... In Edge or other browsers, there is no problem at all. I tried everything I could to fix this, but no luck : (

Could anyone point me to a solution? Thank you so much!

Stefaan

Comment: I'd recommend trying to create a minimal example in jsfiddle os a snippet - the code on that site is.. extensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it myself, it was a problem with a 'float' property.